# How to transform negative values into dummy variables?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to create two dummy variables: **a)** one that captures all negative changes in the x1. If there is a negative change ==1, otherwise ==0.

And **b)** that captures all -1 (and higher) changes. For example: 10.5 to 9.5 or from 10 to 9(or from 10 to 6). This one also as dummy: if -1 or more change then ==1, otherwise ==0.

Sine the data looks something like this, the variable should capture negative values for each personID.

```
   personid  year   x1
    33       1990    0
    33       1991    3.5
    33       1992    2.75
    33       1993    3.25
    33       1994    6
    34       1990    17
    34       1991    9
    34       1992    16.5
    34       1993    16.75
```

For replication, use the code below.

```
set.seed(100)
mydata <- data.frame(
  x1    = sample(c(0:30, 1.5,5.75,9.25,10.25,11.75), 100, replace = TRUE),
  personID  = rep(c(1:10), each = 10)
  )
```

I tried to generate these variables using `ave`...it doesn't help much. I know that I am not using it correctly but not sure where..

```
mydata$a <- with(mydata, ave(x1, personID, FUN = function(x) c(TRUE, diff(x) !=-1) & x!=-1))
```

EDIT:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(personid = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L), x1 = c(37, 34, 30.75, 29, 37, 32.25, 25.75, 32.5, 27, 31, 
28.5, 23.75, 25.75, 28.5, 28.5, 27.75, 25.75, 25.75, 27.25, 31, 
32.5, 35.5, 27.25, 32.25, 30.5, 28.75, 29.5, 29, 29, 27, 28.75, 
28.75, 25.75, 25.75, 22, 22, 29, 30, 20, 22, 12, 11.5, 10, 14.5, 
24, 15.5, 23.5, 14, 24, 10, 9, 34, 16, 9.5, 19, 31, 20, 9.5, 
9.5, 21, 29, 20, 26, 26, 24.5, 5, 16.5, 18.5, 22.5, 31.5, 23.5, 
20, 15.25, 20.75, 32, 23.5, 25, 20, 27, 22.5, 24.5, 28.5, 18, 
17.5, 18.5, 34, 30.5, 32.5, 31, 27, 31, 31, 35.5, 31, 31, 29, 
31.5, 29.25, 31, 31, 28, 29)), .Names = c("personid", "x1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a combination of (1) some *split-apply-combine* approach (`tapply` in base R, `ddply` in `plyr`, `group_by` + `mutate` in `plyr` ... and (2) `diff`.

Data:

```
set.seed(100)
mydata <- data.frame(
  x1    = sample(c(0:30, 1.5,5.75,9.25,10.25,11.75), 100, replace = TRUE),
  personID  = rep(c(1:10), each = 10)
)
```

You'll have to decide what you want to do about the first/last value in each individual's sequence: is the (first, last) value equal to (NA, 0) ? Here I'm setting the first value to zero.

```
diff_to_dummy <- function(x) {
    c(0,as.numeric(diff(x) <(-1)))
}
```

Now `tapply` applies the function to `x1` for each `personID`; `unlist` puts the values back together.

```
dval <- with(mydata,unlist(tapply(x1,list(personID),diff_to_dummy)))
```

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks a lot. Setting first value is correct. I'm trying to figure out the you code. After replicating it all, i put the dval into my data: `mydata$dval<–dval`. It seems that this dummy captures all -1 changes, is that correct? What if I want to capture smaller negative changes as well(1.25 to 1 for example)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- mydata %>% group_by(personID) %>%
                     mutate(a = ifelse((x1-lag(x1)) < 0, 1, 0)) %>%
                     mutate(b = ifelse((x1-lag(x1)) <= -1, 1, 0))
```

Here, we detect change `group_by` each `personID`. The function `mutate` creates your dummy variable columns `a` and `b`. Instead of using `diff`, test by subtracting the `lag(x1)` from `x1`. The results using your simulated data with `seed=100` except I replaced `x1` with `10.5` in row `2` to illustrate a case where `a` is `1` but `b` is `0`:

```
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [100 x 4]
##Groups: personID [10]

##      x1 personID     a     b
##   <dbl>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
##1     11        1    NA    NA
##2   10.5        1     1     0
##3     19        1     0     0
##4      2        1     1     1
##5     16        1     0     0
##6     17        1     0     0
##7     29        1     0     0
##8     13        1     1     1
##9     19        1     0     0
##10     6        1     1     1
```

---

Alternatively, we can use `diff` to test the conditions, but we then need to prepend the result with `NA` so that what is returned by the function used by `mutate` has the same length as what is input:

```
result <- data %>% group_by(personid) %>%
                   mutate(a = c(NA, ifelse(diff(x1) < 0, 1, 0))) %>%
                   mutate(b = c(NA, ifelse(diff(x1) <= -1, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Hi ans thanks for this. I tried this on my data and got this Error: "incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector" I deleted all NA's but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Boris: is `x1` numeric? From the way you generated your data in the post, it is numeric, but your actual dataset may not be. If `x1` are numbers, then you can wrap **all** instances of `x1` with `as.numeric(x1)` to make it work.

Comment: yes, it's numeric. Not sure what's wrong. It seems to work on the simulated data though...

Comment: @Boris: I suggest you edit your question with **some** of your data **using** `dput` and then we can update our answers appropriately. Also, have you tried wrapping all `x1` with `as.numeric(x1)`? What errors do you get then?

Comment: yes I tried as.numeric() but got the same error. It seems to work with the dput() data. Very confusing..

Comment: @Boris: does the other answer work or does it give the same kind of error?

Comment: @Boris: see if my update using `diff` makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Nope, it doesn't work. I'll look at it more carefully now, there's nothing really strange with the data, it's just ID and x1 variable that I'm interested..